# Как правильно разложить POST запрос?

Tags: php

Отправляю данные ajax-ом:

```
data: {'formData': formData, 'action':'send_mail'}
```

formData - это результат сбора данных формы с помощью serialize()
send_mail - передача названия вызываемой функции (это я пытаюсь наладить ajax отправку почты в wordpress с фронта)

В php функции я получаю результат массива post. Как я понимаю formData является просто строкой вида  admin_email=admin.fdr%40gmail.com&main_register=true
Как правильно разложить данную строку на "ключ-значение" для дальнейшей отправки на почту?

Comment: А вы уверенны что данные приходят именно в виде admin_email=admin.fdr%40gmai........ Проверяли ?

Comment: Да. Если я просто отправляю $_POST['formData'] без обработки, то приходит именно такая строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать `parse_str`

```
$params = 'admin_email=admin.fdr%40gmail.com&main_register=true';
parse_str( $params, $output );

print_r( $output );
/*
Array
(
    [admin_email] => admin.fdr@gmail.com
    [main_register] => true
)
*/
```

Или использовать просто `explode`

```
$data = explode('&',$params);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Спасибо! parse_str помог